# Update element after successful AJAX call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

**Problem**

After a successful AJAX call, I want to update an element on page. However, it is not being updated.

**Code [Javascript]**

```
$(function()
{
    $(".upvote").click(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).parent().find("input").val();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "process.php",
            data: "id=" + id +"&f=u",

            success: function(results)
            {
                $(this).parent().parent().find("span.ups").empty().append("Upvotes: " + results);
                console.log(results);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Code [HTML]**

This code is being generated by PHP.

```
<div class="post">
    <h2>$title</h2>
    <p>$body</p>
    <span class="ups">Upvotes: $upvotes</span>
    <span class="downs">Downvotes: $downvotes</span>
    <span class="total">Total votes: $t_votes</span>
    <div id="links">
        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="$id">
        <a href="process.php?id=$id&f=u" class="upvote"><button>Upvote!</button></a>
        <a href="process.php?id=$id&f=d" class="downvote"><button>Downvote!</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Returned by PHP**

The updated number of upvotes.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) Or actually, what's the problem?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Updated* It element is not being updated after AJAX call. However, on refresh, I can see the updated value.

Comment: Could you show us your PHP also? What is the log returning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this` is not what you think it is. Its value is determined by how the function it appears in is called (and will change when inside a different function).

I've no idea what it will be in a jQuery success callback, but it won't be an HTML element.

If you want it to be the clicked upon element, then you need to store it while `this` is that element.

```
$(".upvote").click(function() {
    var clicked_element = this;
```

Then you can use that variable later on:

```
$(clicked_element).parent().etc
```

Comment: I had no idea; thanks for the clarification. This works. Cheers!

Comment: I think `this` is the XHR object in a jquery success handler.

Comment: Yeah, `this` in that context is probably either a standard XHR object or a jquery extended (jqXHR) one.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `this` keyword like that.

```
var that = null;

$(function()
{
    $(".upvote").click(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).parent().find("input").val();
        that = $(this);
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "process.php",
            data: "id=" + id +"&f=u",

            success: function(results)
            {
                that.parent().parent().find("span.ups").empty().append("Upvotes: " + results);
                console.log(results);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I didn't test this, but it should work.

Cheers.

Comment: `$(that)` on success should be `that` instead in your example.

Comment: Nice point, thanks for observation. I was in a copy-paste rush. Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` inside the `success` callback is not the element you might think it is. It would probably be better to cache the parent object instead and traverse from there:

```
var $post = $('.post');

//... $.ajax etc

success: function() {
    $post.find('.ups').etc //...
```